# Where to verify the settings during startup

Tags: django

After settings.py executes, I need to check to make sure all the settings were found from the .env variables, and error out if they are not. Where's the appropriate place to put that logic? Right in settings.py? manage.py?

Answer (score 0):

`i would advice  you django-environ, check documentation at https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

once put in via pip install django-environ, create .env go into the foundation of your project:

in /.env

After that inside  settings.py, you can use your predefined environment variables like:`

````
import os

# django-environ
# https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
import environ

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Load and read .env file
# OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', False)```
````